# Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init exitcode=0x0000009

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, shutdown

firstly I'm newbie in linux, I facing this issue when try to restart or shutdown my laptop. It just stuck in CLI with `Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init exitcode=0x0000009`.
I'm trying to update my BIOS to the newest, but not solve my problem. please help me to find out this way, cause I can't restart or shutdown my laptop :(.
and this is the error image :
[image of detail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C4RU.jpg)

[EDIT]

When I run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display`, this is the output :
[lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtiOt.png)

When I run `ls -al /boot` and then `dpkg -l *nvidia*` :
[result ls -al /boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68uK8.png)

Ubuntu version : 18.04 LTS

Laptop : VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X430FN_S430FN

Comment: What is the graphics adapter?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: If you can get to the GRUB menu, can you boot to Recovery Mode, or to a previous kernel? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, I'm already add more information about graphics adapter please check @Pilot6

Comment: btw I'm still can boot my linux, but not with restart and shutdown, this problem only show when I'm trying to shutdown or restart @heynnema

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`, and tell me what version Nvidia driver? `dpkg -l *nvidia*`.

Comment: Already did sir, based on second image, seems kernel using nouveau instead of nvidia. @heynnema

Comment: You needed to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: You're missing 4 symlink files in /boot... but you've reinstalled Ubuntu... and that probably recreated them for you.

Comment: @Pilot6 FYI... please see my answer. Moot now because OP upgraded and the symlinks got recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re: *"facing this issue when try to restart or shutdown my laptop. It just stuck in CLI with Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init exitcode=0x0000009"*

Here is your /boot...

[image]

You're missing 4 symlinks in /boot. Here's an example of my /boot...

[image]

Your upgrade to 20.04 restored these symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm solve this problem with upgrading linux from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, maybe this could be your references when facing the issues like me. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing 4 symlink files in /boot. Did you delete them? The upgrade probably restored them.